# Redux state show as Map, unable to access combineReducers properties

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

In mapStateToProps it's supposed to be as easy as accessing the key for the section of state you want, and get the state parameter but I am unable to do so.

main app.js file

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDom from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router/immutable'
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'

import configureStore from './store/configureStore'

import App from './components/partials/App'

const history = createBrowserHistory()

const store = configureStore(history)

ReactDom.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <App/>
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('reactDiv')
)
```

configureStore.js

```
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux'
import { routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router/immutable'
import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable'
import { connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router'

import AppReducer from './reducers/app'

const createRootReducer = history => combineReducers({
        router: connectRouter(history),
        app: AppReducer
    })

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

export default function configureStore(history) {
    const middleware = [routerMiddleware(history), thunkMiddleware]

    const rootReducer = createRootReducer(history)

    return createStore(rootReducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware)))
}
```

appReducer

```
/**
 * App level reducer
 */
const initialState = {
    accounts: [],
    employees: []
}

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ACCOUNT_SELECTION_LIST_LOADED':
            return {...state, accounts: action.payload}
        case 'EMPLOYEE_SELECTION_LIST_LOADED':
            return {...state, employees: action.payload}
    }
    return state
}

export async function fetchAccountsSelectionList(dispatch, getState) {
    makeAjaxRequest('/getList/accounts', 'GET', null, response => {
        const accounts = JSON.parse(response)
        dispatch({type: 'ACCOUNT_SELECTION_LIST_LOADED', payload: accounts})
    })
}

export async function fetchEmployeesSelectionList(dispatch, getState) {
    makeAjaxRequest('/getList/employees', 'GET', null, response => {
        const employees = JSON.parse(response)
        dispatch({type: 'EMPLOYEE_SELECTION_LIST_LOADED', payload: employees})
    })
}

export default reducer
```

Primary component (shrunk down to save space)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap'
import { FormControl, InputGroup, Navbar, Nav, NavDropdown, NavLink } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchAccountsSelectionList, fetchEmployeesSelectionList } from '../../store/reducers/app'
import Select from 'react-select'
  
class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state =  {
            billId: '',
            invoiceId: '',
            manifestId: ''
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchAccountsSelectionList()
        this.props.fetchEmployeesSelectionList()
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const {name, checked, value, type} = event.target
        this.setState({[name]: type === 'checkbox' ? checked : value})
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <Navbar variant='dark' bg='dark' className={'navbar-expand-lg', 'navbar'}>
                    <LinkContainer to='/'>
                        <Navbar.Brand>Fast Forward Express v2.0</Navbar.Brand>
                    </LinkContainer>
                    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls='responsive-navbar-nav' />
                    <Navbar.Collapse id='responsive-navbar-nav'>
                        <Nav className='ml-auto'>
                            <NavDropdown title='Bills' id='navbar-bills'>
                            </NavDropdown>
                            <NavDropdown title='Invoices' id='navbar-invoices'>
                            </NavDropdown>
                            <NavDropdown title='Accounts' id='navbar-accounts' alignRight>
                            </NavDropdown>
                            <NavDropdown title='Employees' id='navbar-employees' alignRight>
                            </NavDropdown>
                            <LinkContainer to='/app/dispatch'><NavLink>Dispatch</NavLink></LinkContainer>
                            <NavDropdown title='Administration' id='navbar-admin' alignRight>
                            </NavDropdown>
                        </Nav>
                    </Navbar.Collapse>
                </Navbar>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='xxx' component={xxx}></Route>
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}

const matchDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        fetchAccountsSelectionList: () => dispatch(fetchAccountsSelectionList),
        fetchEmployeesSelectionList: () => dispatch(fetchEmployeesSelectionList)
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
         accounts: state.app.accounts,
         employees: state.app.employees
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(App)
```

So. When I log out the "state" that mapStateToProps is receiving, it is a Map, not an object, that looks like this:

[state results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epmTm.png)

Why doesn't my state look like any of the tutorials I've seen? I have been unable to find any other example like this, except for one that said to just iterate through manually - but since that is not the "correct" way, I must be configuring store incorrectly

I should note that the developer tools seem to be able to access state perfectly, and reflect what I would expect to see. Why can't I access state.app.accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using two packages that rely on Immutable.js data structures, rather than plain JS objects: `import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable'` and import { routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router/immutable'.

In particular, that `combineReducers` from `redux-immutable` is going to cause the root state object to be an Immutable.js `Map` instance, instead of a plain object, and that `Map` instance has `.get()` and `.set()` methods instead of plain fields.

[We strongly recommend *against* using Immutable.js in Redux apps at this point](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#use-plain-javascript-objects-for-state).

Instead, you should write your state as plain JS objects and arrays, and you should be using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux) to set up your store and write your reducers.

Please go through the official ["Redux Essentials"](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) and ["Redux Fundamentals"](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-1-overview) tutorials in the Redux core docs to learn how to use Redux Toolkit to write Redux logic.